# Error writing video in Emgu Cv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to record a video captured from a webcam using Emgu CV but I a, getting an exception.

```
_capture = new Capture(0);
_capture.QueryFrame();
captureOutput = new VideoWriter(@"output.avi",
                                (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
                                (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
                                (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                                (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT),
                                true);
Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
captureOutput.WriteFrame(frame);
```

I am getting an "Attempted to divide by zero." exception when I am executing captureOutput.WriteFrame(frame) line.

Comment: Ok solved the problem. The issue was with the selecting the proper codec to record. I changed part of line 3 below:
_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
with -1. This provided me with a dialog box with the list of codec available on my machine. I selected "Uncompressed" codec and the video was properly generated.

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem. Please post this as an answer. [It's ok to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @Shivam: please post your solution as answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Cite from Comment:

The issue was with the selecting the proper codec to record. I changed part of line 3 below:

`_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC)` with -1.

This provided me with a dialog box with the list of codec available on my machine. I selected "Uncompressed" codec and the video was properly generated.